# How to start asyncio server on remote server with Python?

Tags: python, ipython, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, remote-server

I have a virtual server available which runs Linux, having 8 cores. 32 GB RAM, and 1 TB in addition. It should be a development environment. (same for test and prod) This is what I could get from IT. Server can only be accessed via so-called jump servers by putty or direct tcp/ip ports (ssh is a must).

The application I am working on starts several processes via multiprocessing. In every process an asyncio event loop is started, and an asyncio socket server in some cases. Basically it is a low level data streaming and processing application (unfortunately no kafka or similar technology available yet). The live application runs forever, no or limited interaction with the user (reads/processes/writes data).

I assume, IPython is an option for this, but - and maybe I am wrong - I think it starts new kernels per client request, but I need to start new process from the main code w/o user interaction. If so, this can be an option for monitoring the application, gathering data from it, sending new user commands to the main module, but not sure how to run processes and asyncio servers remotely.

I would like to understand how these can be done on the given environment. I do not know where to start, what alternatives there are. And I do not understand ipython properly, their page is not obviuos to me yet.

Please help me out! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You just described a bunch of stuff how your project is roughly working but you haven't really said what your exact problem is. What is an "asyncio server"? Your code already starts several processes, why do you have a question about how to start a new process from the main code? What do you mean by "how  run process remotely"? That would just ssh connect to it and run the process in terminal.

Comment: Ok. I have the environement described above. I am not allowed to use my laptop for full stack python development due to data protection.
My task is to create an app described above. In the app every module is a separate process, every process starts an async event loop, and in every loop few tasks are defined, including creating socket servers.

Problem: find the proper system and set it up.

Comment: Checked Anadonda, and in Jupyter Notebook (JN) you send a code to the IPython kernel to be processed remotely. Working in several JN page you start several kernels remotely, they can work together via TCP/IP sockets if you want. You can also start subprocesses and in every sub-process a new event loop.

How to merge codes of different JN pages (processes) into a single code bases with this setup? Goal: there is a controller module which should start other modules (processes). Can it be done somehow? 

What other options are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research and learning I came across to a possible solution in our "sandbox" environment. First, I had to split the problem into several sub-problems:

- "remote" development
- paralllization
- scheduling and executing parallel codes
- data sharing between these "engines"
- controlling these "engines"

Let's see in details:

- Remote development means you want write your code on your laptop, but the code must be executed on a remote server. Easy answer is Jupyter Notebook (or equivalent solution) although it has several trade-offs, also other solutions are available, but this was faster to deploy and use and had the least dependency, maintenance, etc.
- parallelization: had several challenges with iPython kernel when working with multiprocessing, so every code that must run parallel will be written in separated Jupyter Notebook. In a single code I can still use eventloop to get async behaviour
- executing parallel codes: there are several options I will use :

  - [iPyParallel](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) - "workaround" for multiprocessing
  - [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - execute JNs with parameters from command line (optional)
  - using %%writefile magic command in Jupyter Notebook - create importables
  - os task scheduler like cron.
  - async with eventloops
  - No option yet: docker, multiprocessing, multithreading, cloud (aws, azure, google...)
- data sharing: selected [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/), took time to learn but was simpler and easier than writing everything on pure sockets. There are alternatives but come with extra dependency, and some very useful benefit (will check them later): [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Redis message broker](https://redislabs.com/solutions/use-cases/messaging/), etc. The reasons for preferring ZMQ: fast, simple, elegant, and just a library. (Knonw risk: our IT will prefer RabbitMQ, but that problem comes later :-) )
- controlling the engines: now this answer is obvious: separate python code (can be tested as JN code but easy to turn into pure .py and schedule it). This one can communicate with the other modules via ZMQ sockets: healthcheck, sending new parameters, commands, etc....